# how to write more words on the same line

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

Is there any way to write the number **37** from the below image on the same line with equal sign?

[image]

```
\textbf{3.} Afla\c ti de\^ imp\u ar\c titul \c stiind c\u a \^ intre \^ imp\u ar\c titor, c\^ at \c si rest avem rela\c tia $i^2+c^2+r^2=37$.
```

Thanks!

Comment: could you give us some starting code, preferably an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: You could reduce the textsize, or put it inside a `\makebox[\linewidth][l]{text}`

Comment: Can you show us a little more context? With **3.** it seems like you're manually enumerating content. Is this the case? Does the line start at the left margin, or indented?

Comment: The simplest solution is to use \mbox{$...$} to make the inline math unbreakable.  The results my be a bit ugly, with either a large gap or extending into the margin.

Comment: Short answer: no. If TeX breaks the line at the equals sign, it's almost sure that the number and the period cannot fit.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than enclosing the math formula inside `\mbox`, as John Kormylo suggests, I’d define a command that prohibits line breaks inside a math formula.  Indeed, this allows the glue inside the formula to stretch and shrink together with other glue on the same line, whereas John’s solution does not.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\prohibitmathbreaks}{%
    \binoppenalty \@M
    \relpenalty \@M
}

\hyphenpenalty = \@M % ONLY for this example: DO NOT INCLUDE IN YOUR DOCUMENTS!

\makeatother



\begin{document}

Some meaningless text, inserted just to get near\ldots\ the end of the line.
\( x+y=a+b\prohibitmathbreaks \).
And some more random text that adds other lines, which~contain~an unbreakable
sequence of words, to show that the spaces inside the formula \emph{are} allowed
to shrink.

On the other hand, if one uses the \verb|\mbox| solution, this does not happen:
\mbox{\( x+y=a+b \).}
And: some more random text that adds other lines, which~contain 
unbreakable~sequences~of~words.

Another paragraph, containing another formula, in order to show that the effect
of our \verb|\prohibitmathbreaks| command is kept local:
\( a+b+c+d+e = x+y+z \).

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output of the code]